# Inherit SOME but not all arguments from parent class's constructor? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, parent-child

Let's say I have parent class P

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c
```

If a create another class C which is a child class of P, is it possible to inherit SOME parameters of P but not all (Let's say I just want parameters a,c from class P to be passed on to C). I know it's a weird question, and I don't know if there's an application to this, but I just can't seem to find an answer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good way to do it as far as I know is to do something like the following:

```py
class P:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

class C(P):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(C, self).__init__(a, b, c)
        self._b = b
```

Essentially, you call the superclass constructor to define all of the values, but then override the value (in this case, for `self._b`) later in the child class constructor.

Alternatively, if you don't want `self._b` to even be a thing in the class `C`, you can also do `del self._b` after the `super().__init__()` call to remove it altogether.

In general, though, it seems like bad practice to have a child class **not** have some of the fields that the parent class has, since other parts of the code may rely on that field being there.

Comment: did you mean ```del self._b``` since I only want ```a``` and ```c```? Yeah I'm aware that it would be bad practice in most cases. I just want to know in case I run into a problem that might need it. For example, we can define Animal class to have ```eyes```, but some fishes in the lowest depth of the ocean adapted by losing their eyes, then that ```NoEyeFish``` class which still is-a ```Animal``` just happens to not have ```eyes```. I know it might be a bad example, but I think it's possible that we can run into something like that

Comment: Right, sorry. I'll edit it to match your example. :)

Comment: In that case, it's probably best practice to have an abstract class in-between something like `AnimalWithEyes` instead of doing this.

Comment: @JakeNguyen yeaaa this is sort of the reason why inheritance is often considered just not that great of a technique. Not everything in the world fits into neat hierarchies, indeed, most of it doesn't. Prefer composition over inheritance. If you run into something like this, *then don't use inheritance*

Comment: @MLavrentyev I can see how that would work, but if we have to create a proxy-class (for lack of better words) for each feature we don't need, then it would get kinda messy you know? But you're right, I think we won't likely run into something as complex, but I just find it interesting to think about.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, you're right. I was just curious if it's something possible to be done in Python :)